# Python Neural Network library/program with simple installation? (Solved?)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Edit: I found a solution to my problem; there's a scipy installer that doesn't require openBLAS, and that seems to have worked.

I'm trying to find a neural network library for Python, but nothing I've tried has been what I've wanted; the libraries a lot of people seem to be recommending (e.g Keras, scikit-learn) require scipy, which won't actually install on my computer.  (I think it requires openBLAS, which doesn't seem to have a tutorial for installation.)  I did find a program that looks like it will work, but it has a maximum of one hidden layer.  Can someone point me to a library that actually works, or show me how to install scipy?

Comment: What operating system are you using? And what happens when you try to install scipy?

Comment: We cannot really get into finding/recommending software here, and especially looking for edge-case stuff like alternatives to mainstream libraries. Please instead make your question about problem you have when installing `scipy`, so give details about your computer (OS, Python ver), what you have tried, and what actually happens when you do e.g. `pip install scipy`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying out neural networks, I would recommend [keras](http://keras.io), it is a wrapper around TensorFlow. With just a few lines of code, you can build a neural net.

Scikit learn is really good for ml algorithms like logistic or linear regression, naive​ Bayes, svm and others. I am not sure if it is good enough for neural networks.

I would still think, you would require some blas library.

Comment: "Scikit learn is really good for ml algorithms like regression, naive​ Bayes, svm and all. I am not sure if it is good enough for neural networks." do not understand this comment. You can use neural networks for a regression task

Comment: I mean logistic or linear regression sort of algorithms.

Comment: Ok makes sense now, I edited your comment accordingly